# Intermittent munin-cron error “There is nothing to do here, since there are no nodes with any plugins”

Tags: linux, centos, monitoring, munin, system-monitoring

We've installed munin monitoring on one of our servers.  Generally it seems to be working well but occasionally, 4 times in 2 months to be exact, munin-cron has generated the following error:

> [FATAL] There is nothing to do here, since there are no nodes with any plugins. Please refer to http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/FAQ_no_graphs at /usr/share/munin/munin-html line 38

On searching for this error I can only find issues where munin is not working at all, rather than the intermittent problem that we're facing.

Some help preventing this error or how to debug it would be much appreciated.

We're running CentOS 5.5, Munin 1.4.5 installed using yum.

Comment: The error message is defined in `HTMLOld.pm`, after checking the output of get_group_tree() for sanity. You may try upgrading your Munin install (to 1.4.6, or even 2.0, if possible), there are quite a few changes in this module recently: http://munin-monitoring.org/log/trunk/master/lib/Munin/Master/HTMLOld.pm . The 1.4.5 release is built from SVN revision 3627 (two years ago!) and the current revision of the file is 4579.

Comment: We upgraded to 1.4.7 but the error is still appearing

Comment: I have that problem too. Every night at around 03:00 I get the same email but munin is somehow working fine. Can't find any hint where it tells me the problem. Did you find an Answer to this? Upgrading to a newer version isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying your munin configs via configuration management you are probably running into a timing issue where the config file is being created while the munin cron is trying to run.